# Best way to get new Image in Javascript using canvas

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas

I am making a game with the html5 canvas and I am having some trouble getting the images on screen.

```
//player img
var img1 = new Image();
    img1.onload = function() {
      console.log("image loaded");
    };
    img1.src = "player.png";
```

The image is a .png file called "player" and is saved on my desktop.  Am I doing something wrong when setting the src method?  Is there a better way to do this?  I appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking ... *Drawing you img:* Your image will draw when it's fully loaded as long as you put `context.drawImage(img1,0,0)` in your `img1.onload`. *Organizing img.src files:* If you're roughing out a design on your dev computer then putting all page files (including the .png) on the desktop is fine. When you go into production on a web server you traditionally create a root directory containing your index.html and you create a subdirectory for each type of file ( root/js, root/css, root/images, etc ).

Answer (score 1):

Well first, the image should have a path that is relative to the html document and if you are not seeing the image, it's probably because you didn't put that relative path into your code (you are only using the file name which implies the image is in the same directory as the html file).

Also, you haven't shown any code to associate the image with the canvas. This is the approach:

```
    // Get the DOM object reference for the canvas element:
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    // Get an object reference for the canvas' contextual environment:
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Instantiate an image to use as the background of the canvas:
    var img = new Image();

    // Make sure the image is loaded first otherwise nothing will draw.
    img.addEventListener("load", function () {
      // Draw the image on the canvas at position 0, 0 (top-left):
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    });

    // Wait until after wiring up the load event handler to set the image source
    // This example assumes that the image is located in a sub-folder of the current folder, called images.
    // Your path must be a relative reference to the location where the image is.
    img.src = "images/starfield.jpg";
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but how would I find the relative path to the photo? Could I use C:\Users\Me\Desktop\player.png?

Comment: "Relative" simply means where is something based on my current location, so you must start with the location of the .html file (that's the "You are here" spot). To reference something one folder up (parent folder) you would use two dots and a slash followed by the file you expect to be there: ../player.png. To reference something that is in a sub-folder, start with the name of the sub-folder that is in the same folder that your .html file is in and then put the file name that you have in that folder, like:  images/player.png

Comment: Don't use the path that you wrote (C:\...). That's not a relative path, that's an absolute path and will only work when you view the web page from your computer. When you publish your work to a host, you aren't going to publish your C:\Users\Me\Desktop folder.  You should create a working directory and then create sub-folders of that directory for the supporting files your site is going to need (images, css, scripts, etc.). The .html files go in the working directory and the supporting files are organized by type into the sub-folders.